# Cloudformation AllowedPattern match dots and hyphens

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to get a Cloudformation script to enforce a valid url path which could contain version information. I am trying to match something like:

/mypath-1.2.1

I am using

`"AllowedPattern": "/[/a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*",
"Default": "mypath-1.2.1"`

I have checked the regex against an online checker and it is fine but I am getting a "*Template validation error: Template format error: JSON not well-formed*" on the backslashes.

It will validate ok without the backslashes but fails on the default value not matching the regex

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`AllowedPattern` is a `JSON` string and must follow the JSON standard for strings.

Your `AllowedPattern` contains escape sequences like `\-` and `\.` which are invalid in `JSON`.

You need to escape the black slashes in the `AllowedPattern` to make this valid `JSON`;

```
"AllowedPattern": "/[/a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]*"
```

The `JSON` [specification](http://www.json.org/) only allows escape sequences that follow these rules;

[image: JSON string]

Comment: Great. It worked. I would have assumed the pattern would force literal backslashes so never thought to try that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: Why do you escape period and dash inside character class? I thought they were literal inside character class `[` and `]`...

Comment: @georgealton What should be the pattern for supporting space as well?